# How to search one column data from table1 to all the column of table 2 and then extracting selected attributes

Tags: sql

I have a data in column 1 of table 1 with multiple rows, i have to search all the data one by one to all the column of table 2 and wherever match comes, i want all the records from table 2 using SQL.

Really would be great help if i get the solution.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
  join (select distinct column1 from table1) t1
    on t1.column1 in (t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3 ...)
```

The sub-select, i.e. `(select distinct column1 from table1)`, is used to find the values to search for in table2's columns.

`JOIN` with these values, where all table2's columns are searched for each value.

Answer (score 0):

Think you are talking about `INNER JOIN` like

```
select t2.* from table2 t2 inner join table1 t1 
on t1.column1 = t2.column1
  or t1.column1 = t2.column2
  or t1.column1 = t2.column3
  ....
```